# setting log level ignored

Tags: logging, kotlin, configuration

I am using kotlin with gradle and it works great except I can not configure  the log level for my `SimpleLogger`

I have a one line `src/main/resources/simplelogger.properties` with the following content:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug
```

this is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.snc.token_model.HelloWorldKt'

defaultTasks 'run'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple
  compile 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.6'
  compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}

jar {
  manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'demo.HelloWorldKt' }
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = "4.10.2"
}
```

and this is my main function

```
package com.snc.token_model

import mu.KotlinLogging

fun getGreeting(): String {
    val words = mutableListOf<String>()
    words.add("Hello,")
    words.add("world!")

    return words.joinToString(separator = " ")
}

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    logger.debug { "********** debug log **********" }
    logger.info { "********** log **********" }
    println(getGreeting())
}
```

when I run `./gradlew` I get the following output

```
> Task :run
3 [main] INFO com.snc.token_model.HelloWorld - ********** log **********
Hello, world!
```

there should be an additional line with `********** debug log **********`

Comment: I had also issues with sl4j-simple with respect to io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging.

I just use a "full" logger implementation for sl4j, which is described here 
https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/a-guide-to-logging-in-java